# preg_replace with encryption function

Tags: php

I'm trying to take some data in a string and replace it with an encrypted version.

Here's a data sample:

```
encrypted=1|5|a|6|4|9
encrypted=1|1|a|3|4|9
encrypted=5|5|a|6|6|9
```

Here's what the code looks like right now -

```
preg_replace("^(encrypted)(=)(.*)^", 'encrypted='.$this->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',"$3"), $data);
```

I've been reading up on preg_replace_callback, but I'm not sure this is the answer considering I can't call $this from within the function and can't replicate the function into the callback as it's extremely long (100+ lines).

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this answer [Codeigniter preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241625/codeigniter-preg-replace-callback)

```
$that = $this;
$content = preg_replace_callback("^(encrypted)(=)(.*)^", function($matches) use ($that) {
return $that->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt',$matches[3]);
}, $data);
```